# How to resume process on applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

So I have around 4 viewcontrollers in this iPAd App that I am testing. Before the Application becomes inactive, the **TableViewController** is presnet. Once I press the button on the iPhone, it will initiate

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

And when I start it again, I want the application to resume with the process, with the loaded table and show the 'Screen' that was available before I pressed the Button.

I can understand that

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

is involved in this event. Could you tell me how I can actually bring a particular view controller on the event of resuming the process ??

Thanks.

Comment: applicationWillResignActive is not supposed to be invoked manually. It's a callback that gets invoked automatically when you press the home button to exit an app which then gets put into multitasking mode. What are you exactly trying to do? If you say it in detail, someone here will be able to help implement a cleaner solution which would go about things the correct way :) ....

Comment: @Siddharth Iyer: Sorry Man. I am new to StackOverflow - I had no idea I needed to accept answers... Sorry about it. I have edited the question and added information about the table view controller.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry! I was just being nice and letting you know before someone flamed you lol ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register your own UIViewControllers as observers for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification.

In your view controllers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Do not forget to remove them as observers in their dealloc methods:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    [super dealloc];   
}
```

Comment: Can I register all UIViewControllers as Observers  and get back all of them at the same time ?

Comment: @Legolas: A notification can have multiple observers. And as long as the viewControllers are in memory they will act on those observers. But when you say "get back all of them" what do you mean?